# retrieving data from database does not work on this code

Tags: php, mysql

categories databse table:

```
id  | name  
1   | electronics
2   | Automotive
```

classifieds database table:

```
id  user_id  category_id    cover          title       price    description 
102  1       2              iamges/1.jpg    blabla     10      blablabla
```

I get an error saying: Notice: Undefined variable: name1 in **\post.php on line 49

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$res2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `classifieds` WHERE `id` = '" . $id . "' LIMIT 1");

if($res2 && mysql_num_rows($res2) > 0){
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res2)){
        $id = $row['id'];
        $user_id = $row['user_id'];
        $category_id = $row['category_id'];
        $price = $row['price'];
        $cover = $row['cover'];
        $title = $row['title'];
        $description = $row['description'];
        $profile_data = user_data($user_id, 'username');

        $res3 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `categories` WHERE `id` = '" . $category_id . "' LIMIT 1");
        if($res3 && mysql_num_rows($res3) > 0){
            while($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($res3)){
                $id1 = $row1['id'];
                $name = $row1['name'];
            }
        }  
    }
}else{
    echo 'error';
}echo $name;
```

why do i get the error for the echo $name1; ?

Comment: is the query working fine??

Comment: mysql_query returns false on failure. Please check with mysql_error. Also mysql_* funtions are deprecated, try to use mysqli or PDO instead

Comment: give another variable name for $row in while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res3)) as you have given the same name $row for the above query result also.

Comment: use mysqli it is recommended

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should print the query and run in php myadmin driectly and see if it returns correct result.

you threewhile loops contains same `$row`. please change below one to some else

```
 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res2)){

and 

  while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res3)){
  ------^
```

change to some else like `$row3`

```
  while($row3 = mysql_fetch_assoc($res3)){
        $id = $row3['id'];
        $name = $row3['name'];
    }
```

Comment: that appeared to fix the problem, but now $name is undefined when i echo it.. why is it doing that?

Comment: please tell which line it is  saying undefined.   $name = $row3['name']; or some other line. please make sure name field is in categories table

Comment: Undefined variable: name1 in *\post.php on line 49. that line says: <?php echo $name1; ?> (the while has $name1 = $row1['name'];). and yes the databse does have 'name'

Comment: Please can you update or post that code that has issue. because in above code id don't find $name1. It seems because of value not set please declare this variable on top of page out side of loop somewhere. $name1='';

Comment: just updated the code, placing $name1 outside the loop won't echo what i need though right?

Comment: I was referring to initializing the variable. please do one thing more please do a print_r of $row3. print_r($row3); and let me know the output. let us see what db is returning

Comment: it doesn't display anything if i put it in the loop. If i replace it with the echo $name it shows an error saying undefined $row3 (or $row1 for my code above)

Comment: please do one thing EDIT and Paste all the code so i can see where can be issue. as from above it is not appearing issue any where. I will post correct code then.

Comment: just updated the code at the very top, notice the echo $name; at the end

Comment: thanks for posting code. i see it meanwhile can you do two things.
1. add $name = ''; on top like under $id = $_GET['id']; add $name = ''; ( for initializing) 

2. add print_r($row3) inside loop  while($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($res3)){

and let me know the out put.

Comment: the error is gone as $name is empty and nothing else is displayed, print_r($row3); isn't doing anything for some reason

Comment: ok if print_r is not printing anything it means there control is not inside while. may be no value is returned. can you do one thing echo query "SELECT * FROM `categories` WHERE `id` = '" and run it directly in PHPMYADMIN see if it given result there.

Comment: also try to echo  mysql_num_rows($res3). see if it has some value in it. this will tell what exactly is going on

Comment: i get the error: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in. not entirely sure how to test directly from phpmyadmin.. i clicked go and it tells me there is syntax error

Comment: do an echo for this like echo "SELECT * FROM `categories` WHERE `id` = '" . $category_id . "' LIMIT 1"  under  $res3 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `categories` WHERE `id` = '" . $category_id . "' LIMIT 1");

run your page this query will be printed  and copy it and go to SQL tab in phpmyadmin and run this there.

Answer (score 1):

you are using `$row` in both sql queries user `$row2` and `$row3` like given below

try this

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$id = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($id));
$res2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `classifieds` WHERE `id` = '" . $id . "' LIMIT 1");

if(mysql_num_rows($res2) > 0){
    while($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($res2)){
        $id = $row2['id'];
        $user_id = $row2['user_id'];
        $category_id = $row2['category_id'];
        $price = $row2['price'];
        $cover = $row2['cover'];
        $title = $row2['title'];
        $description = $row2['description'];
        $profile_data = user_data($user_id, 'username');

        $res3 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `categories` WHERE `id` = '" . $category_id . "' LIMIT 1");
        while($row3 = mysql_fetch_assoc($res3)){
            $id = $row3['id'];
            $name = $row3['name'];
        }

    }   
}
```

**UDPATE 2 :**

as you tell that you are using a query in function `user_data`

```
$data = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT $fields FROM users WHERE user_id = $user_id"));
```

change it as

```
$data = "";
$res_data = mysql_query("SELECT $fields FROM users WHERE user_id ='$user_id' LIMIT 1 ") or die(mysql_error());
if($row_data = mysql_fetch_assoc($res_data))
{
   $data = $row_data['your_field_name'];
}
```

Comment: good point! I still however get the same errors.. Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in ***\post.php on line 20

Comment: check in your `user_data` function are u using any sql in that?

Comment: yeah, $data = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT $fields FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` = $user_id"));

Comment: if i change the two codes i get a million errors and it even logged me out of the website. is that the only way?

Comment: what you want to store in `$data` variable in `function`

Comment: that's the user information like password, email, username.. i don't think the issue would be there, i think it's something to do with the way the category_id (classifieds db) and id (category db) are matched

Answer (score 1):

The error

`"Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in *\post.php on line 20 line 20"`

means that the `mysql_query();` function has `not executed successfully` .

May be check the "id" value received or not.

Answer (score 1):

Try this ...

replace with this..

```
$res2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `classifieds` WHERE `id` = $id  LIMIT 1");
```

also

```
$res3 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `categories` WHERE `id` = $category_id  LIMIT 1");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $res2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `classifieds` WHERE `id` = '" . $id . "' LIMIT 1");

    if($res2 && mysql_num_rows($res2) > 0){
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res2)){
            $id = $row['id'];
            $user_id = $row['user_id'];
            $category_id = $row['category_id'];
            $price = $row['price'];
            $cover = $row['cover'];
            $title = $row['title'];
            $description = $row['description'];
            $profile_data = user_data($user_id, 'username');

            $res3 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `categories` WHERE `id` = '" . $category_id . "' LIMIT 1");
            if($res3 && mysql_num_rows($res3) > 0)
                while($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($res3)){
                    $id = $row1['id'];
                    $name = $row1['name'];
                }
            }   

        }   
    }
```

Comment: this seemed to get rid of the main error, now when i echo $name1 is tells me it's undefined